# Read and write Unicode character from Json file using Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, unicode, character-encoding

I am trying to read the below json data using attached Python code (Python V3.5.1) but **the issue is** that **Character representation ç as Ã§ and £ as Â£**.
Please help me with the code which will correctly read and write data to and from the file, without changing the format or char set

Json Data:

```
{
    "config":[{
            "filetype": ".csv",
            "coldelimiter":"ç",
            "rowdelimiter":"£"
    }]
}
```

**Python code:**

```
import json
import os

fileLoc=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"appconfig.json")
json_data=open(fileLoc).read()
print(json_data)
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "config":[{
            "filetype": ".csv",
            "coldelimiter":"Ã§",
            "rowdelimiter":"Â£"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to avoid implicit encoding and decoding.

When you use `open()` to read (or write) text files (such as JSON, but unlike XML), then the file contents are decoded with some default encoding.
Which default encoding is used depends on your environment; you can see this with `locale.getpreferredencoding()`.

So let's assume that *appconfig.json* is stored on disk with UTF-8, but your locale is configured to use Latin-1, then the letter *ç* will be misinterpreted as the sequence *Ã§*. Confirm:

```
>>> 'ç'.encode('utf8').decode('latin1')
'Ã§'
```

If this is the case, then it's easy to fix: specify the encoding on `open()`:

```
with open(fileLoc, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    json_data = f.read()
```

There's another possible (but less likely) explanation: Maybe the default encoding is already UTF-8, thus the data is decoded correctly when read from the file.
The `print()` expression then encodes the data, again using UTF-8, thus sending a sequence of bytes to STDOUT which is exactly the same as the file content.
But then, your terminal (or whatever you use to execute the script) *misinterprets* the output as Latin-1, such that they are displayed as garbled characters.

If the latter is the case, then you need to fix the terminal configuration (to accept UTF-8), or re-encode `sys.stdout` (with `sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('latin-1')(sys.stdout)`, but I don't recommend that).

Comment: Thanks @lenz, yes thats exactly I did and now its working. On different note , I am new to Unix env. I think source code  build and tested in Win env are still work in Unix env provided same Python version is used .
For file path or location I am using os package like join(sourceLoc, file), hope my understanding is fine. For windows path could be c:\filelocation and in Unix could be /var/sp/filelocation/
any document \ material around Python on unix  will be helpful.

Comment: @RintG I'm not sure I understand. There are a few things that need care if you are trying to write code that is portable across OSes, and using `os.path.join` to write paths is certainly a good choice. If you have a more concrete question about Python on Unix, post a separate question.